# Alternatives to sudo's password prompt?

Tags: sudo, password, yubikey, elevation

I know sudo can be setup with NOPASSWD so that it will not ask for a password when executed.

This is more of a security for a person with ADHD/ADD rather than 'best security' - I understand the false sense of security compared to a full blown password prompt.

I *do want* to be prompted, but I'd like a more 'Windows' like approach of either:

- Get a yes/no prompt for elevation.
- Better yet, be prompted for a PIN/alternative secret - that is short.
- Even better yet, approve action via a USB connected Yubico key.

Is there such a solution?

Comment: This should be possible via /etc/pam.d/sudo using the libpam-u2f module - see [How to configure a U2F key(such as a YubiKey) for system wide 2-Factor Authentication?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071027/how-to-configure-a-u2f-keysuch-as-a-yubikey-for-system-wide-2-factor-authentic)

Comment: Would  not recommend a change. Get used to it. That prevents trouble. That's why Linux doesn't need creepy antivirus software

Comment: I've been used to it for the past 30 years, I'm looking for improving my workflow - and other's in the process.